# FabricJS - add line to canvas and control only it's length

Tags: javascript, html, fabricjs

I am using FabricJS to develop a simple floor plan editor. When adding a Line (that should be a wall) to the canvas, I want the ability to control only the length of the line, not it's width-height.

I have tried setting `lockScalingY: true` but the problem is that when adding a line the control handles are so close to each other that I can't interact only with the horizontal control handles... the corner handles actually block the horizontal handles...

How can this be done?

Comment: Even looking at the demos on http://fabricjs.com it appears that it's buggy (on Chrome anyway)

Answer (score 2):

**Fine control of adjoining FabricJS lines**

The way graphics programs like photoshop deal with this common problem is to let the user position lines *near* the desired intersection and then use the arrowkeys to "nudge" the line into place pixel one at a time.

The code below illustrates a rough solution that does the same thing for FabricJS lines:

1. User selects a line.
2. Turn off the control handles and borders.
3. Let the user "nudge" the line into perfect alignment (here the line length is increased).
4. Turn the the control handles and borders back On.

This is just "proof of concept" code.  In your production app:

- You'll probably want to use arrowkeys instead of buttons to "nudge".
- I made nudging go 10px at a time--you might do this 1px at a time.
- And when the user starts nudging, you'll automatically turn off the handles and borders for them.

Here is code and a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/dd742/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="fabric.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; padding:30px; }
    canvas{border: 1px solid red; }
</style>

<script>
    $(function(){

        var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
        var selectedLine;

        var line1=newLine(50,100,150,100,"red");
        var line2=newLine(160,50,160,150,"green");
        canvas.add(line1,line2);

        function newLine(x1,y1,x2,y2,color){
            var line=new fabric.Line(
                [x1,y1,x2,y2],
                {fill:color,strokeWidth:15,selectable:true}
            );
            return(line);
        };

        $("#hOff").click(function(){
            selectedLine.hasBorders=false;
            selectedLine.hasControls=false;
            canvas.renderAll();
        });

        $("#hOn").click(function(){
            selectedLine.hasBorders=false;
            selectedLine.hasControls=true;
            canvas.renderAll();
        });

        $("#shorter").click(function(){
            changeLineLength(selectedLine,-10);
            canvas.renderAll();
        });

        $("#longer").click(function(){  
            changeLineLength(selectedLine,10);
            canvas.renderAll();
        });

        function changeLineLength(line,adjustment){
            if(!selectedLine){return;}
            if(line.get("y1")==line.get("y2")){   // line is horizontal
                line.set("x2",line.get("x2")+adjustment);
            }else
            if(line.get("x1")==line.get("x2")){   // line is vertical
                line.set("y2",line.get("y2")+adjustment);   
            }else{    // line is diagonal
                line.set("x2",line.get("x2")+adjustment);   
                line.set("y2",line.get("y2")+adjustment);   
            }
        }

        canvas.observe('object:selected', function(eventTarget) {
            var event=eventTarget.e;
            var target=eventTarget.target;
            selectedLine=target;
        });

    }); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <p>Select a line,</p><br/>
    <p>Turn handles Off</p><br/>
    <p>Make lines intersect by pressing longer/shorter</p><br/>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="200"></canvas> 
    <button id="hOff">Handles Off</button>
    <button id="shorter">Shorter</button>
    <button id="longer">Longer</button><br/>
    <button id="hOn">Handles On</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the effort with this answer. It is not the way I wanted the interface to be because I want to let the user change the wall length using the mouse, but it is an interesting alternative solution. Is there a way to hide only some of the control handles?

Comment: No, the control handles are displayed as a group without granular control of the individual handles. So the options are a refined version of this hack or modifying the source code are your options.  BTW, the source code is available and well commented if you want to go there ;)

Answer (score 0):

May be helps somebody.

Add handler to event

```
'object:selected': _objSelected
```

Then at handler set unneeded control to false.

```
function _objSelected(e) 
{
    if(e.target.objectType == 'line')
    {
        var cv = e.target._controlsVisibility;
        // mt - middle top, tl - top left and etc.
        cv.mt = cv.mb = cv.tl = cv.bl = cv.tr = cv.br = false;
    }
}
```

Also I added objectType (custom property) and padding (for beauty) to new object Line

```
var obj = new fabric.Line([50, 50, 150, 50], { padding: 10, objectType: 'line' });
```